# Shared Banner iOS

Tags: ios, shared, banner

My App uses Navigation Controller. I am implementing ads with adMob SDK, mediating adMob and iAd.

Since the user can switch the views, i wanted to use a shared banner. I have googled for hours, but I do not get this to work.

I was trying a tutorial i found here: http://googleadsdeveloper.blogspot.co.il/2012/04/creating-gadbannerview-singleton-in.html

so I followed it. It says just add

```
shared = [GADMasterViewController singleton];
[shared resetAdView:self];
```

to any view that should show the banner, but when I add this to a `viewWillAppear` in a view, Xcode says

> "use of undeclared identifier shared".

What am I doing wrong? sorry I am new to programming ;)

So when i just declare "shared" in that viewController, it won t call that "shared" from the `GADMasterViewController` right? So how can I access that ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to declare it...

```
GADMasterViewController *shared = [GADMasterViewController singleton];
[shared resetAdView:self];
```

or just

```
[GADMasterViewController singleton] resetAdView:self];
```

Comment: Thank you, after some days and try and error i figures it out !